# Exchange 2010, Message tracking hung

Tags: windows, exchange-2010

I am unable to access Outlook 2010 Message tracking tool.
we have tracked that all services related to the exchange are active.
the message tracking tool gives login page, but at login, there is no progress.

how could i find the service/ component that is blocker

however i am concerns of the message tracking in GUI mode, and i have not tried the powershell mode

Comment: Which MS Exchange 2010 version are you using? There are some issues in Exchange which are fixed when you run the latest CU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue : message tracking, troubleshooting GUI were hung
Fix:, restarting IIS, transport service and reset virtual directory(server configuration>>client access>>CAS server >>reset virtual directory) fixed the problem.